# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.github.dandelion.core.web.AssetRequestContext.get(AssetRequestContext.java:147)

Tags: java, jsp, datatables, dandelion

### Migrating from dandelion datatables 0.10.0 to 1.1.0

Hi I am trying to upgrade dandelion datatables in my project and I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.github.dandelion.core.web.AssetRequestContext.get(AssetRequestContext.java:147)at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.AbstractExtension.addBundle(AbstractExtension.java:224)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.feature.PipeliningFeature.setup(PipeliningFeature.java:71)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.AbstractExtension.setupWrapper(AbstractExtension.java:138)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.ExtensionProcessor.process(ExtensionProcessor.java:83)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.ExtensionProcessor.process(ExtensionProcessor.java:74)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.extension.ExtensionLoader.loadExtensions(ExtensionLoader.java:66)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.generator.DatatableJQueryContent.<init>(DatatableJQueryContent.java:107)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.setupHtmlGeneration(TableTag.java:385)
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:254)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.program.viewProgram_jsp._jspx_meth_datatables_005ftable_005f0(viewProgram_jsp.java:243)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.program.viewProgram_jsp._jspService(viewProgram_jsp.java:104)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:675)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:669)
at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f4(layout_jsp.java:255)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:127)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**JSP Code**

```
  <datatables:table id="studentMeetingtbl" url="getStudentMeetingList" serverSide="true" processing="true" 
  row="studentMeeting" rowIdBase="id" rowIdPrefix="studentMeeting_" 
  displayLength="5" lengthMenu="2,5,10,15,25,50,100"    jqueryUI="true" 
  filterable="true" sortable="true"  
  autoWidth="true" pageable="true" 
  paginationType="full_numbers" 
  stateSave="true" >
  <datatables:column title="Id" property="id" filterable="false" sortable="false" searchable="false" visible="false" />
<datatables:column title="Actions" renderFunction="actions" filterable="false" sortable="false" searchable="false" display="HTML" />
<datatables:column title="Id" property="id" />
<datatables:column title="Group Name" property="group.groupName" />
<datatables:column title="Project Name" property="group.projectName" />
<datatables:column title="Meeting Date" property="meetingDate" renderFunction="ParseDateColumn"/>
<datatables:column title="Next Review/Meeting Date" property="nextReviewDate" renderFunction="ParseDateColumn"/>
<datatables:column title="Remarks" property="remakrs" />
</datatables:table>
```

Comment: @EJP: this is not a duplicate of the standard Java NPE question.  This author is not a [contributor to Dandelion Datatables](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables/graphs/contributors) so I don't believe he/she could reasonably be expected to debug the Dandelion code.  And it's not as if they're passing a `null` value into `doEndTag()`: [that method](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables/blob/master/datatables-jsp/src/main/java/com/github/dandelion/datatables/jsp/tag/TableTag.java#L224) takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded this jar files and issue solved.

```
jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar
jackson-core-2.7.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
```

And added filter in `web.xml`

```xml
<!-- Dandelion-Datatables servlet definition -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.servlet.DatatablesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/datatablesController/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion servlet definition and mapping -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion filter definition and mapping -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```